# phone numbers loaded to my c# .net core web app from an excel file has encoding issues

Tags: c#, .net-core, memorystream, openxlsx

I'm loading a collection of rows from excel into a `MemoryStream`. the excel contains a phone number column.
for example:

> phoneNumber="0511234567"

up untill now I had no issues with my code. I got an excel file that causes the folling problem:
on the example above, if I will run the follwing command I will get:

`phoneNumber.Length()` ==> 11 // it should be 10

`phoneNumber.Substring(0,2)` ==> "0"

`phoneNumber.Substring(0,1)` ==> ""

`phoneNumber.SrartsWith("05")` ==> true

in my code I check if `phoneNumber.Substring(0,2) == "05"` and in this excel file I get `false` though when I look at the actual value it is starting with "05".
As you can see above it seems like the first char is nothing and is counted as if there is a value.

I understand this relates to something with encoding. I tried parsing to bytes and decoding and then encoding to no success.
Will appriciate any input.

Comment: what's the result of `(int)phoneNumber[0]`?

Comment: @yehor the result is 8207. the value in the phone number is "‏0549497889"

Comment: The character code for '0' (zero) is 48 so if you have 8207 there it is not a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce the behavior by adding a null to the beginning of the phone number:

```cs
var phoneNumber = "\00511234567";
```

So you probably have a non-printing char at the beginning of the string. To trim control characters from the string you can use the following:

```cs
phoneNumber = new string(phoneNumber.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray());
```

##### Update:

Since the first char has char code 8207 which is not a control character. You could use `IsDigit` instead and if the phone numbers are allowed to have a hyphen you could add that as a filter condition:

```cs
phoneNumber = new string(phoneNumber.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c) || c == '-').ToArray());
```

Comment: Thank you @nikstra i trie you suggestion but still same behaviour as described above. I changes to: 'item.MobilePhone = new string(item.MobilePhone.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray());'

Comment: @Shio If the phone numbers are only digits you can replace '!char.IsControl(c)' with 'char.IsDigit(c)'.

Answer (score 0):

The first character in your string is a Chinese symbol, so it might not be displayed in debug output if you don't have Chinese installed locally. I would suggest just doing `phoneNumber.Substring(1)` to extract the phone number if it always starts with a single unreadable symbol

Comment: Thank you @Yehor - I do have other charecters like a hyphen or space that I'm excpecting to receive. your input regarding the identity of the char in [0] location was amazing! thank you.